# Show animated text for mulitple API calls using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to make a list of web api calls(for eg: 20) on a user click. Each web api is to update particular user. I m looping through each user and calling the web api using $.ajax() method.

In order to show the progress, I m using a spinner. Below the sprnner I wanted to show progress of each web api call. That means in success of web api call I wanted to show the user name detials(for eg: John's Information updated). So the the text should change for every success call and set the html value. I wanted to show this as animated text one after the other.

John's Information updated
Next -> Sam's Information updated
Next -> Dan's Inforamtion updated
....so on

Note: Above line should be shown one at a time. its not append, its replace of name for every success call.

```
for(var i=0; i < userArray.Length; i++)
{
   $.ajax(
      url: '<some url>',
      method: 'PUT',
      data: userData,
      sucess: function(response){
          $('#displayText').html(`${userData.Name}'s Information Updated`);
      }
   );
}
```

The above code is not showing the user names one by one, its not changing the value of the displayText id in every service success call and showing the progress in anumated way.

I also tried using setInterval and setTimeOut inside the success but no luck.
Please help.

Comment: is the data being sent correctly to the server?

Comment: All those requests will be done very quickly ... too fast to see each update unless you append them rather than overwrite the innerHTML for each one

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is async, so when you throw that into a loop you are actually calling all the requests in parallel and not sequentially. If you want to do a sequential requests you will want to use a queue/stack. See the example below.

```
function updateUser(user) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: '<some url>',
      method: 'PUT',
      data: user
   });
}

function updateUsers(users, onUpdate) {
  const queue = users.slice();
  
  const dequeue = () => {
    if (queue.length > 0) {
        const user = queue.shift();
      
      updateUser(user)
        .then(function () {
            onUpdate(user);
        })
        .always(function () {
            dequeue();
        });
    }
  };
  
  dequeue();
}


updateUsers([1,2,3], function(user) {
     $('#displayText').text(`${user.Name}'s Information Updated`);
});
```

Calling `updateUsers` with a list of users will queue an update for a single user and will wait for them to finish. After each successful update `onUpdate` is called with the user so that you can decouple user update logic with view specific things.

Also notice the use of `.text()` instead of html. Since you are using user input, a user can potentially have a name that is html such as `<script>alert('hahaha')</script>` and you will execute any code the malicious user wants. Please see [xss](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/)